# From one razorpage to another with a link

Tags: html, css, razor-pages

I'm making a login form with the use of empty razor pages, i want to have the user either login with the form or register. when the register link is pressed nothing happens.

Code for button & link in login page:

```
 <div class="button_container">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
            <a href="../Register">Register</a>
        </div>
```

picture of how te pages are stored:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think that i fixed it with changing the code into this:

```
 <div class="button_container">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
            <a asp-page="../ModNews_Pages/Register">Register</a>
        </div>
```